# How to use a js string into a asp query?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have two js vars options and app in the app var I want to store the name of the application that I'm looking for and then used it in the SELECT but I'm not getting any result, the main issue probably is the way I'm trying to concat the js variable to the query.

```
var options = [];
var app = "StackOverflow";

<% ="Hello "& app %>    
<%strSQL = "SELECT * FROM APP WHERE NAME ='"& app &"')"
     rs.open strSQL, session("Conn")%>
     <%Do Until rs.Eof%>
        <%Response.Write(strSQL)%>
          options.push({text: "<%=rs.Fields("ELEMENT_ID")%>", value: " 
          <%=rs.Fields("ATTRIBUTE_VALUE")%>"});
     <%rs.MoveNext Loop%>
<%rs.close%>
```

Here is the source of the page I only get the Hello String but I can't concat the variable it should be: "Hello StackOverflow"

[image: Source output]

Comment: Debugging! It's what SO is terrible at! What is the actual query this code is making? Not what you think it is making, but what is the actual string? If you took that exact query and ran it outside the code, does it work? Then work from those known areas to the unknown.

Comment: you got an upvote from me, to encourage you to edit your question in order to make it more clean. it would be very helpful if you check what the actual HTML will look like after server side processing.

Comment: you're trying to access a client side variable server side, which you cannot do. Remember, everything in between <%  %> GETS EXECUTED FIRST! therefore, your sql's WHERE clause will always be where name = ''   If you want to pass data from your client back to the server, you need to either POST the data using forms or insert the data into into the url and use GET.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery first person to make a bit of sense. To be clear everything inside <% %> is executed at the server before the response is even sent. The JavaScript is executed at the client after receiving the servers response, it's a [chicken and egg scenario](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg).

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoshMontgomery that makes sense I will change the logic of the function.

Comment: Hi first page hidden value form in ex: document.getElementById("myvalue").value = "StackOverflow";
post or get data value request.querystring or request post methot use.